# How can I use duplicated loop in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I use duplicated loop in React.js?

I have array in array and I want to use it.

I have an array. And Objects are in the array. And the other array is in these Objects.

```js
state = {
  myInformation: [
    {
      name: "jessie",
      age: 27,
      interests: ["react", "vue"]
    },
    {
      name: "ellie",
      age: 26,
      interests: ["java", "spring"]
    }
  ]
}

...

const information = this.state.myInformation.map(
  ({name, age, interests}) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
    <div>{age}</div>
    <div>{interests}</div>
  )
)

...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another **map()** inside.

```
const information = this.state.myInformation.map(
  ({name, age, interests}) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
    <div>{age}</div>
    <div>{interests.map(interest => <div>{interest}</div>)}</div>
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show item in "interests"?

```
const information = this.state.myInformation.map(
  ({name, age, interests}) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
    <div>{age}</div>
    <div>{interests.join(', ')}</div>
  )
)
```